# Pyquery get value of "srcset" attribute

Tags: python, srcset, pyquery

I'm trying to extract `srcset` attribute of a `img` tag using pyquery & python3.

```html
<img alt="my-image" srcset="//url/i/need/to/extract">
```

Extracting `alt` attribute works like expected, and returns "my-image"

```py
(".item-thumb img").attr('alt')
```

But this method doesn't work for the attribute `srcset`. It returns `None`

```py
(".item-thumb img").attr('srcset') #doesn't work
(".item-thumb img").attr.srcset #doesn't work
```

How to solve this? If there is no built-in way, may be a regular expression? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, although the attribute is just `srcset`, you need to use `data-srcset` instead. This line works like a charm.

```py
(".item-thumb img").attr('data-srcset')
```

I don't know what is the reason for this behavior though.